# MVC view not opening in VS2012 page inspector

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In an mvc [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-page-inspector-in-aspnet-mvc) on asp.net website it is explained that we can see the view file (.cshtml) when some part of page is selected on the page loaded in browser inside visual studio 2012. But I can't see the respective view (full or partial) when clicked on the loaded page. Only windows I can see are the rendered html and css as shown on the bottom of the loaded page.

[image]

Am I missing any option which opens the respective view when we have a selection on page? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar problem when trying to access the designer through page inspector. This was fixed after I install the VS2012 Update 1 package.